# iterate through two lists simultaneously and skip first element

Tags: c++, list, for-loop, vector

What if I want to iterate over two lists/vectors using

```
for (const auto& a : list) { 
 for (const auto& b : list) {
   if ( a == b ) {
     *do something* 
   }
 }
}
```

and I want to know if an element exists more than once inside of that list.
How do I skip the first element so it won't compare the exact same elements.
Like, what's the `const auto&` equivalent to:

```
 for (size_t i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  for (size_t j=i+1; j < list.size(); j++) {
     if (list.at(i) == list.at(j)) {
         *do something*
     }
 }
}
```

I know I could add an `int i{0}`and only *do something* when `i > 0` but it kinda didn't work correctly when my code looked like this:

```
for (const auto& a : list) { 
 for (const auto& b : list) {
 int i{0};

   if ( i > 0 && a == b ) {
     *do something* 
   }
 }
}
```

Is there a better way to do it? Am I having a brain fart? Did I make a mistake when I added an integer?

Comment: "*Did I make a mistake when I added an integer?*" - Yes. Move your `int` out of the inner loop into the outer loop, eg: `for (const auto& a : list) { int i{0}; for (const auto& b : list) { if ( i > 0 && a == b ) { *do something* } } }`

Comment: Are you talking simultaneously, as in parallel, or what you have displayed, which is nested, or are you talking about threading?

Comment: @RemyLebeau i even forgot to `++i` lmaoo but no it didn't work...i feel like i almost had it though.....but i'll just use the normal for loop thx

Comment: @ThomasMatthews oh yeah i think i meant nested...

Answer (score 2):

Range-based `for` loops always iterate every element from the very beginning to the very end of a container.  There is no option to skip elements.  If you need that, you will have to use a traditional `for` loop using indexes or iterators instead.

Comment: thank you! i'll use the traditional one then!